# PHP print_r works but return doesn't work

Tags: php

When i call this function it doesn't return the data(using return alone) but when i use print_r it works.

This is connector.php

```
  class Connector
{

        public function Connect() {

          $client = new Client(null);
                $cookiePlugin = new CookiePlugin(new ArrayCookieJar());
                $client->addSubscriber($cookiePlugin);

            private $MainPageURL = "http://example.com";
            $login_url = $this->GetMainPage($client, $this->MainPageURL);

       }

            private function GetMainPage($client, $url) {

                        $request = $client->get($url);

                        $response = $request->send();

                        $data = $response->getInfo('url');

                        return $data; // doesn't work
                        print_r($data); //works 

                    }

}
```

and client.php contains

```
require 'connector.php';
$connector = new Connector($datos);
$con = $connector->Connect();

  echo $con["login_url"];
```

Comment: How do you determine that `return` doesn't work? What happens when you try to `print_r(GetMainPage( value , value ));` ?

Comment: When i call this function it doesn't return the data (without print_r).

Comment: Please read the post again, i have stated that i called the function $x = GetMainPage(a,b); and then echo $x; .

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't become clear from the question as is. Could you provide a link/ fiddle/ full code?

Answer (score 2):

print_r !== echo

Is your data an array or object by any chance?

try

```
var_dump($x);
```

to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing up `return` and `echo`. `return` doesn't output anything, but allows you to use the value outside of the function, like this:

```
$johndoe = GetMainPage('x', 'y');

echo $johndoe;
```

Often you may see this used using PHP's short echo syntax: `<?=`. The result will look like this:

```
<?=GetMainPage('x', 'y')?>
// This is short for:
<? echo GetMainPage('x', 'y'); ?>
```

Anyway, you need to do something with the function's result, otherwise the value is just lost in oblivion. That is, if the function returns a result. Some functions just 'do' something and don't return anything.

Comment: Yes i know. I have stated that i called the function $x = GetMainPage(a,b); and then echo $x; but it doesn't return the data. but it returns data when i put the print_r in there.

Comment: actually you haven't stated it - you may want to edit the question

Comment: Maybe the difference between `print_r` and `echo` is the problem. What happens if you call `print_r($x);` or even `print_r(GetMainPage('x', 'y'));`?